# Additional natural boundary conditions determined by $G(y(b))$ outside of Lagrangian.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Here is a problem I am not quite sure how to approach:

Determine the natural boundary condition at $x=b$ for the variational problem defined by $$J(y) = \int^b_a L(x,y,y')dx + G(y(b)),$$ where $ y\in C^2[a,b]$ and $y(a) = y_0$. I know the solution, but I don't know how to arrive to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function.

In a typical way of physics, you may have, by repeating the derivation of Euler-Lagrange equation,
\begin{align}
0=\delta J[y]&=\delta\int_a^bL(x,y,y'){\rm d}x+\delta G(y(b))\\
&=\int_a^b\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\delta y+\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\delta y'\right]{\rm d}x+G'(y(b))\delta y(b)\\
&=\int_a^b\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\delta y{\rm d}x+\int_a^b\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}{\rm d}\delta y+G'(y(b))\delta y(b)\\
&=\int_a^b\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\delta y{\rm d}x+\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\delta y\Bigg|_{x=a}^{x=b}-\int_a^b\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)\delta y{\rm d}x+G'(y(b))\delta y(b)\\
&=\int_a^b\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)\right]\delta y{\rm d}x+\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))+G'(y(b))\right]\delta y(b)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}(a,y(a),y'(a))\delta y(a).
\end{align}

In the above result, due to the arbitrariness of $\delta y$ for all $x\in\left(a,b\right)$, the first term implies
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\right)=0,
$$
namely the well-known Euler-Lagrange equation. Due to the arbitrariness of $\delta y$ at $x=b$, the second term from above forces
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}(b,y(b),y'(b))+G'(y(b))=0.
$$
This gives the boundary condition for $y$ at $x=b$. Due to the imposed boundary condition $y(a)=y_0$, it is a must that $\delta y(a)=0$, and the last term from above vanishes.

Mathematically, you may always make the above derivation more rigorous. That is, let
$$
y=y(x,t)
$$
be a family of feasible functions. That is, for each fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
y(x,t)\in C^2\left[a,b\right],\quad y(a,t)=y_0.
$$
Now, suppose $y=y(x,0)$ corresponds to the optimal function that minimizes the functional $J$. Then it is a must that
$$
0=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\Bigg|_{t=0}J[y(\cdot,t)]=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\Bigg|_{t=0}\left(\int_a^bL(x,y(x,t),y'(x,t)){\rm d}x+G(y(b,t))\right),
$$
where we adopt the notation
$$
y'(x,t)=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(x,t).
$$
You may carry out this derivative, and the arbitrariness of
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(\cdot,t)
$$
would give you exactly the same equation and boundary condition as above.

Comment: Mhmm okay. The arbitrariness of $\delta$ is what kind of bugs me here.

Comment: @physicsmajor: $\delta y$ is a perturbation of $y$, where $y$ is supposed to be the function that minimizes your functional. If you are not getting along with $\delta y$, simply regard it as another function $z=z(x)$, which satisfies that $y+z\in C^2$ and that $\left(y+z\right)(a)=y_0$ (and because $y(a)=y_0$, this is equivalent to $z(a)=0$). These are the only requirement for $z$, and you could see that there are infinitely many possible $z$ you could take. This is called the arbitrariness of $z$.